# Asks me to specify electronVersion in a webdriverio/electron project, but I already have

Tags: electron, selenium-chromedriver, wdio

Working on a webdriverIO project for an electron app. When I try to run it it tells me:

```txt
Error in "undefined"
Error: Failed to initilialise launcher service "electron":
Error: You must specify the electronVersion, or provide a chromedriverCustomPath value
    at new ChromeDriverLauncher (file:///C:/Users/Me/Myproject/node_modules/wdio-electron-service/dist/launcher.js:62:50)
    at initialiseLauncherService (file:///C:/Users/Me/Myproject/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/initialiseServices.js:97:39)
    at async Launcher.run (file:///C:/Users/Me/Myproject/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:69:65)
    at initialiseLauncherService (file:///C:/Users/Me/Myproject/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/initialiseServices.js:118:15)
    at async Launcher.run (file:///C:/Users/Me/Myproject/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:69:65)
```

However in my wdio.config.js, I've already done that:

wdio.config.js

```js
services: [
    'chromedriver', {        
        logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log', 
        outputDir: 'driver-logs',
        args: ['--silent']
    },
    'cucumber-viewport-logger',
    'electron',
    {
        appPath: join(dirname, './packages/client/.build/main.js'),
        appName: 'appname',
        appArgs: [''],
        binaryPath: './node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd',
        chromedriver: {
            port: 9519,
            logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log',
        },
        electronVersion: '^13.1.4',
    },
],
```

I took that formatting exactly from the docs.

package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",
    "@types/command-line-args": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/execa": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.18.0",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^8.5.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.5.8",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.5.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.5.8",
    "chromedriver": "110.0.0",
    "command-line-args": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
    "electron-wix-msi": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "execa": "^4.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-cucumber-viewport-logger-service": "^1.0.4",
    "wdio-electron-service": "^4.0.0",
    "webdriverio": "8.5.8",
    "yarn-run-all": "^3.1.1"
}
```

Can anyone deliver salvation? I don't know what the issue is. I even tried to put in a chomedriverCustomPath and got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and resolved removing `^` from version:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "electron": "<exact version>" # without ^ or ~
  }
}
```

***wdio.conf.js***

```
const electronVersion = require('./package.json').devDependencies.electron
...

{
        appPath: join(dirname, './packages/client/.build/main.js'),
        appName: 'appname',
        appArgs: [''],
        binaryPath: './node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd',
        chromedriver: {
            port: 9519,
            logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log',
        },
        electronVersion: electronVersion,
    }
```